# PHP HTML MathJax write with text

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

i use mathjax and convert success dynamic.

but mathjax result in tag.

i want mathjax result in textarea tag and write text with mathjax.

so I changed div -> textarea but not working a mathjax.

```
<textarea id="MathOutput" class="output" name="txtSender">$${}$$</textarea>
```

my source code.

```
<script>

  (function () {
    var QUEUE = MathJax.Hub.queue;  
    var math = null, box = null;    
    var HIDEBOX = function () {box.style.visibility = "hidden"}
    var SHOWBOX = function () {box.style.visibility = "visible"}

    QUEUE.Push(function () {
      math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathOutput")[0];
      box = document.getElementById("box");
      SHOWBOX(); // box is initially hidden so the braces don't show
    });

    window.UpdateMath = function (TeX) {
      QUEUE.Push(
          HIDEBOX,
          ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX],
          ["Text",math,"\\displaystyle{"+TeX+"}"],
          SHOWBOX
      );
    }
  })();
</script>


<input id="MathInput" size="80" onchange="UpdateMath(this.value)" />

<div class="box" id="box" style="visibility:hidden">
<textarea id="MathOutput" class="output" name="txtSender">$${}$$</textarea>
</div>


<script>
  if (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMSIE) {
    MathInput.onkeypress = function () {
      if (window.event && window.event.keyCode === 13) {this.blur(); this.focus()}
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: A `<textarea>` can only contain plain text, not formatted text, so MathJax output can not be put into a `<textarea>` tag.